# Call popover on dynamically added element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap popovers on my page.

```
$('.myEm').popover({
        'animation': true,
        'content': myContent,
        'placement': 'top',
        'html': true
});
```

However, when I add a new element with jquery, by adding it to the DOM, without refreshing the page, my popover code on the new element does not work.

Normally I'd bind it by using .on(), but that doesn't seem to work in this case:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myEm', function(){
    $(this).popover({
        'animation': true,
        'content': myContent,
        'placement': 'top',
        'html': true
    });
});
```

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: "doesn't seem to work in this case" So what happens instead? How does it misbehave in that case?

Answer (score 0):

This may seem fairly obvious but have you tried

```
$('.myEm').click(function(){
     $(this).popover({
        'animation': true,
        'content': myContent,
        'placement': 'top',
        'html': true
     }); 
});
```

Comment: There's no need for this complexity. $('.myEm').popover({ }); works fine, but not when the element is added to DOM with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer that may deal with binding better would be something like

```
     $(document).on('popover', '.myEm', function(){
            'animation': true,
            'content': myContent,
            'placement': 'top',
            'html': true
     });
```